# Importing Pyside-2 project into my web site built by Django

Tags: python, html, django, user-interface, pyside2

I have a UI project by Pyside 2 in python.
Also I have a web site built base on Django.
I want to know if it is possible to run my UI project in the web site?
Is there a way to convert the UI code into Html or just a simple way to put my UI code in HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that will work. According to my knowledge, Pyside -- which is basically Qt for python -- is only workable as an executable, which will not translate into Django. Django's templates are default rendered to HTML files where you can load css and js files into it.

If you're just getting started on the frontend, I'll recommend using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), only in case you don't know where to start.

Comment: Thank you. I think so. I was looking for ways to convert my UI  to an app which I could import into setting.py                                                                                                 
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'bootstrap4'
]

Comment: I don't believe that will work though. In a Django application, the app itself must handle both frontend and backend and it will be complicated to integrate with another app. The `bootstrap4` app is specifically designed to work with Django's form rendering. Your UI is something that unfortunately is incompatible with Django.